# View Variable not recognized and setOnClickListener not available?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am new to Android dev and working on my first application. It is a fairly simple app but I am running into a strange error.
I want to put a clicklistener on an image so I first initialized an ImageView variable then when I try to reference it, it does not show in autocomplete.
Furthermore when I try to call setOnClickListener() on it, that also throws an error. Perhaps I forgot something crucial. Please advise. My XML and Java for main activity are pasted below

I tried to:
- Invalidate caches and restart
- Restart android studio
- Restart PC
- Clean project
- Remake project from scratch

My Main Activity Java:

```
package com.example.android.obgynconference2020;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    ImageView startImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.starting);

}
```

My Main Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/start"
        android:id="@+id/starting"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always Initialize your widgets inside onCreate method and so Onclickliteners

```
onCreate(){.....
ImageView startImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.starting)
starImg.setOnClickListener....... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    ImageView startImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.starting); //<------- this is the problem

    }
```

please initialize startImg variable in the onCreate() method like below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView startImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.starting);
// and put here onclick listner

    }



}
```